# Images aren't loading in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, express, phaser-framework

I'm following [the Phaser game tutorial](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part2), and I'm using the function

```
function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
    this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
    this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
    this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
    this.load.spritesheet('dude', 
        'assets/dude.png',
        { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 }
    );
}
```

When I do this, I get a whole bunch of 404 errors, saying `GET http://localhost:4000/assets/sky.png 404 (Not Found)` and so on for all the assets.

So I tried using `this.load.setBaseURL()`, with the parameter as directory the index and assets folder are in. But when I do this, I get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at [image location] from origin 'http://localhost:4000' has been blocked by CORS policy.`

I believe that is discussed [here](https://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3/index), but I don't know a suitable workaround for the error I'm getting. For reference, I'm using Express to serve my page:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/part7.html');
});

http.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:4000');
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I remenber this tutorial. I beleive It's more a express issue thant a phaser one. Try this: `app.use(express.static('assets'))` `this.load.image('sky', 'sky.png');`      take a look to this doc [here] (http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: @MaximeB Ah, ok. I was wondering if it was to do with express. Anyway, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, it's still blocked by CORS policy.

Answer (score 3):

This is my working code for this tutorial:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>TEst phaser game</title>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.16.1/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**game.js**

```
  var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 300},
      debug: false
    }
  },
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
  }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
var score = 0;
var scoreText;

function preload() {
  this.load.image("sky", "assets/sky.png");
  this.load.image("ground", "assets/platform.png");
  this.load.image("star", "assets/star.png");
  this.load.image("bomb", "assets/bomb.png");
  this.load.spritesheet("dude", "assets/dude.png", {frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48});
}

var platforms;
var player;

function create() {
  this.add.image(400, 300, "sky");

  platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

  platforms.create(400, 568, 'ground').setScale(2).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(600, 400, 'ground');
  platforms.create(50, 250, 'ground');
  platforms.create(750, 220, 'ground');

  player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'dude');

  player.setBounce(0.2);
  player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

  this.anims.create({
    key: 'left',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 0, end: 3}),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
  });

  this.anims.create({
    key: 'turn',
    frames: [ { key: 'dude', frame: 4 } ],
    frameRate: 20
  });

  this.anims.create({
    key: 'right',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 5, end: 8}),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
  });

  this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);

  cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

  stars = this.physics.add.group({
    key: 'star',
    repeat: 11,
    setXY: { x: 12, y: 0, stepX: 70 }
  });

  stars. children.iterate(function (child) {
    child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.4, 0.8));
  });

  this.physics.add.collider(stars, platforms);

  this.physics.add.overlap(player, stars, collectStar, null, this);
  ///////////////////////////////////////
  function collectStar(player, star) {
    star.disableBody(true, true);
    score += 10;
    scoreText.setText('Score: ' + score);
    if (stars.countActive(true) === 0)
    {
        stars.children.iterate(function (child) {

            child.enableBody(true, child.x, 0, true, true);

        });

        var x = (player.x < 400) ? Phaser.Math.Between(400, 800) : Phaser.Math.Between(0, 400);

        var bomb = bombs.create(x, 16, 'bomb');
        bomb.setBounce(1);
        bomb.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        bomb.setVelocity(Phaser.Math.Between(-200, 200), 20);

    }
  };

  scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'score : 0', {fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000'});

  bombs = this.physics.add.group();
  this.physics.add.collider(bombs, platforms);
  this.physics.add.collider(player, bombs, hitBomb, null, this);
  function hitBomb(player, bomb) {
    this.physics.pause();
    player.setTint(0xff0000);
    player.anims.play('turn');
    gameOver = true;
  }
}

function update() {

    if (cursors.left.isDown)
      {
        player.setVelocityX(-160);
        player.anims.play('left', true);
      }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
      player.setVelocityX(160);
      player.anims.play('right', true);
    }
    else
    {
      player.setVelocityX(0);
      player.anims.play('turn');
    }
    if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down)
    {
      player.setVelocityY(-330);
    }
}
```

If still doesn't work:

- test it with a simple local server via node. cmd `http-server` in your folder that contains index.html game.js and assets folder. use this file tree

_

```
├── assets
│   ├── bomb.png
│   ├── dude.png
│   ├── platform.png
│   ├── sky.png
│   └── star.png
├── game.js
└── index.html
```

It should work, now with express:

- Put your assets folder in your public folder. And use
  `app.use(express.static('public'))`